# Queue In Struct Within Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, queue

I tried to create an application that using multithreads.
Every worker threads has its own queue to be consumed and processed, while the main thread feeds their queues. The worker threads will be spawned dynamically, according to such conditions.

To maintain information of worker threads for the main thread, each spawned worker thread will be registered to an array:

```
struct workerNode **workerMap = (workerNode**) malloc(MAX_WORKER * sizeof(struct workerNode));
```

while workerNode is struct injected to each worker threads:

```
struct workerNode
{
    int offset;
    queue<dataRecord*> workerQueue;
    short semaphore;
};
```

The problem is, everytime I try to push a `dataRecord*` to a worker thread's `workerQueue`, for more than 1 times, SEGFAULT occurs.
First push is success, no problem, but the second is totally failure.

This is the gdb backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000402382 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::construct(int*, int const&) ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000402382 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::construct(int*, int const&) ()
#1  0x0000000000401e40 in std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) ()
#2  0x0000000000401a83 in std::queue<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >::push(int const&) ()
#3  0x0000000000401361 in listenerProcess(int, char*) ()
#4  0x0000000000401854 in main ()
```

and this is how I call push to the queue:

```
while(workerMap[index] != 0)
{
    workerMap[index]->workerQueue.push(rec);
    index++;
}
```

Can anyone help me? thanks

**EDITED:**

As WhozCraig suggested before, I've done another experiment:

```
struct workerNode **workerMap = (workerNode**) malloc(MAX_WORKER * sizeof(workerNode*)); // storing pointers, not objects
```

I am still using the same way to allocate the `workerMap`. But I changed the way to register `workerNode` to the map.

```
//workerMap[index] = (struct workerNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct workerNode));
workerMap[index] = new struct workerNode;
```

And the application seems fine now. Thanks :)

Comment: Just FYI, if you're working on task-specific worker-threads (thread A does X, thread B does Y, etc). queue-per-thread makes sense. Otherwise you're putting a lot of headache into what should be easy with a single queue shared between all threads. 

Regarding your problem, your queue allocator is choking, which means either the queue is corrupt, or the pointer to it is. How are you allocating the workerNode object? Please tell us you're **not** using `malloc()` like you are for the pointer array you're storing its address in.

Comment: Also, what latch-mechanism locks your queue down during insertion to keep the thread from pulling data while you're inserting it? And who is the last-man that turns off the lights of the inserted item? I'm not sure i understand why the same item is being put into *all* the worker queues? Who actually *owns* it and therefore deletes it when finished? And is this a mistake: `(workerNode**)malloc(MAX_WORKER * sizeof(struct workerNode)` ?? You're not allocating a pointer array (but you're certainly casting it to one). I think your workerNodes are not properly being `new`d but it is hard to say.

Comment: Actually every threads does the same thing, checking mechanism to a data collection. But since, they're differentiated with offsets (ex: Thread A checks index 0-100, Thread B checks index 101-200, ...), we can say that they're task-specific worker threads. And yes, I use malloc() for the workerNode. Does it sounds wrong?

Comment: So who owns the object then? Or is it send to another queue somewhere for final expulsion by a single-owner (and who does *that* if it is)?

Comment: And yes, malloc for workerNode (or **any** C++ object), is **WRONG**). Use array-new.  `workerNode* myArray = new workerNode[ MAX_WORKER ];` or better still, use an `std::vector<>` or `std::array<>`.

Comment: the object is owned by the main thread, the one who spawns it and feeds it with the data.

Comment: ok, so long as the main thread knows when to destroy it (or not to do anything if it is stack-allocated rather than dynamic allocated). I suggest you use a `std::vector<workerNode>` for your pool, btw.

Comment: yeah, first thought was that I wanted to create a dynamic "map", which size can also be dynamically allocated, instead of array. I see that vector is the most rightfull option.

Comment: I think you still have quite a road ahead, btw. each queue will need a concurrency mechanism for protection from main-thread insertion and worker-thread extraction. std lib collections are only thread-safe on concurrent-read; as soon as you throw a writer in there (your main-thread) you need to latch it down at both write *and* read time. you'll likely need this as part of the `workerNode` object. I'd type all this up in an answer, but I think you're better served to just go think about it for awhile longer.

Comment: yup, obviously I will prevent that condition, which is a usual case on multithreading queue mechanism. I'm planning to have a mutex locking for each threads. And I've modified the code as you suggested about allocating the `workerNode`. It seemed that the problem was on the `workerNode` insertion to the `workerNode` array.

Comment: It was assuredly the queue *in* the workerNode that never properly constructed. Lord knows why it worked the first time. Anyway, good luck to you, sir.

Comment: One more thing. you're making that pointer array too large. its being allocated as `(workerNode**) malloc(MAX_WORKER * sizeof(struct workerNode))`. It it should be `(workerNode**) malloc(MAX_WORKER * sizeof(*workerMap))`. Note the pointer type in the `sizeof()`.  You're saving pointers to dynamic objects, not objects themselves, in this thing.

Comment: oh yeah, that was also my mistake, because I thought that I must allocated memories as big as the struct. I've realized that I stored pointers, not structs. Thanks :)